# Guessing Game - Looping Problem in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I had to build a game which awards players based on their guess. The user guesses a number and the algorithm compares that to a randomly-generated 2-digit number and awards the player accordingly.

Problem: The player needs to play this game 3 times before the game ends. When I loop it 3 times with a while loop it only loops by asking the user for their guess and does not print or return the award message. When I remove the while loop and use a for loop it only runs once and prints the message.

How do I solve this looping issue and run this program thrice?

```
import random

jackpot = 10000
award2 = 3000
award3 = 100
noaward = 0
play = 3
turns = 1

def lottery_game():
    for x in range(play):
        lottery = random.randrange(10,99)
        lot = list(map(int, str(lottery)))
    
        guess = int(input("Choose a 2 digit number: "))
        n_guess = list(map(int, str(guess)))
    
        if guess == lottery:
            return "You won: " + str(jackpot) + " Euros"
        elif n_guess[0] == lot[0] or n_guess[1] == lot[1]:
            return "You won: " + str(award2) + " Euros" 
        elif n_guess[0] == lot[1] or n_guess[1] == lot[0]:
            return "You won: " + str(award3) + " Euros"
        else: 
            return "I am sorry, you won: " + str(noaward) + " Euros" + " try again"

while i <= 3:
    lottery_game()
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

- replace `return` with `print` statement:
- replace `while i <= 3` with `for i in range(3)`

Here is updated code:

```
import random

jackpot = 10000
award2 = 3000
award3 = 100
noaward = 0


def lottery_game():
    lottery = random.randrange(10, 99)
    lot = list(map(int, str(lottery)))

    guess = int(input('Choose a 2 digit number: '))
    n_guess = list(map(int, str(guess)))

    if guess == lottery:
        print(f'You won: {jackpot} Euros')
    elif n_guess[0] == lot[0] or n_guess[1] == lot[1]:
        print(f'You won: {award2} Euros')
    elif n_guess[0] == lot[1] or n_guess[1] == lot[0]:
        print(f'You won: {award3} Euros')
    else:
        print(f'I am sorry, you won: {noaward} Euros. Try again')


for i in range(3):
    lottery_game()
```

Sample output:

```
Choose a 2 digit number: I am sorry, you won: 0 Euros. Try again
Choose a 2 digit number: You won: 100 Euros
Choose a 2 digit number: You won: 10000 Euros
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you're not initialising your `i` variable before your `while` you shoud definitely do it. But for your use case, you shouldn't use a `while`, you should use a `for` loop like this:

`for i in range(0,3):`

This will run the code in the loop three times.

Comment: so should i change the for loop in the function or change the while function below it

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialized `i`

Before the while statement add `i=1`

Comment: yea i see i should have used "turns" instead of "i"